# Can I reduce URL String from OpenAM Apache Agent?

Tags: openam

I set up the OpenAM Server and Apache + Agent.

It worked fine.

But, my boss dislike the Long URL String when the first attempt occurred(Log-in Page).

I mean...

- The User try to open www.example.com.
- The Apache Agent redirect to OpenAM Log-in Page.
- In this situation, the Browser shows the URL such as openam.example.com/openam/UI/Login? + Long Query String : module, locale, goto, etc... parameters
- This URL String is made by Apache Agent... Right?

  So, Should I modify Agent codes(C?) and rebuild them?

Comment: if you have more parameters, but 'goto' you propably configured the loginURL to include those.

The agent will use the configured login URL, goto-parameter and the actual requested URL to build the redirect

modifying the agent will not really help

Comment: Thank you for your comments,

 but I think I don't really understand the point.

 I should read the reference more thoroughly. ^^;

 Thanks again...